# LazyLoading through EGOImageView not working with custom cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, egoimageview

I am trying to load images from url with `EGOImageView` [From here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) by using custom cells .
I had tried with

```
-(void)configureReviewCell:(YDRecentReviewCell*)mycell atindexpath:(int)indexPath
{

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: tempPlace.placeProfileImageUrlString];
    NSURL* bijUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: tempPlace.bizlogo];
 EGOImageView*  urlimage = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    urlimage.delegate=self;
    urlimage.imageURL = bijUrl;

    mycell.topimage =urlimage;

}
```

but  image not showing on table view however if I add it as a subview on cell contentview ( `[mycell.contentView addsubView:url image]`)image appears .
what i am doing wrong . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this line

```
mycell.topimage = urlimage;
```

Make sure that topimage is added as a subview to mycell's contentView.

This seems like the fix-

```
mycell.topimage = urlimage;
[mycell.contentView addSubview:mycell.topimage];
```

I presume that **mycell.topimage is nil before you assign any urlimage to it**.
And there is no variable added as subview to mycell.contentView before this assignment.

So you need to add this as subview to mycell.contentView after assignment.

Comment: it gives me image on top left corner

Comment: Because the frame's origin is (0, 0). Just make the frame right. You need to do something like this :- **myCell.topimage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80);** or any other position of your choice.